# ggplot2 geom_bin2d Representation as Percentages of Column Counts

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

How can `geom_bin2d` treat each column of the plot (the `x` aesthetic) as a group of measurements and, instead of counts, represent the data as a percentage of the total count within a column? The solution should not modify the internals of ggplot2, but use existing features of the package, to be general and concise.

Here's an example of the default plotting of counts for each combination of two factors.

```
exampleData <- data.frame(method = sample(c("A", "B"), 10, replace = TRUE),
                          prediction = sample(c("Healthy", "Disease"), 10, replace = TRUE))

ggplot(exampleData, aes(x = method, y = prediction)) + geom_bin2d()
```

Instead of counts, I'd like to have column-wise percentages.

Comment: Can you please add a reproducible example and what you have done so far?

Comment: Yes, I can, and I have.